# How to get a database created in PHPmyadmin up on OpenShift?

Tags: mysql, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

I've made some databases in PHPmyadmin that I need to access through OpenShift. I've added the correct cartridges to be able to do this, but I don't know how to manually upload this database or if OpenShift does this automatically. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: When you say PHPmyadmin, you mean localhost/PHPmyadmin?

Comment: Yes, just from my local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phpmyadmin cartridge provides phpMyAdmin on OpenShift. In order to add this cartridge to an application, the MySQL cartridge must already be present. Once installed, phpMyAdmin can be used by navigating to http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin with the MySQL login credentials.

Using phpmyadmin is the easiest, but this can't be used with scaled applications.

The easiest thing to do would be to scp the database to your gear, and use the mysql command to load it in.

Comment: Great, that is what my friend showed me a minute ago. I already had the cartridge and just didn't realize that next to it is a small icon that brings up phpMyAdmin. Once I did that, it worked fine.